# How to read a gmail with Apache Camel

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, apache-camel, spring-camel

i am trying to read a gmail using the routebuilder() of apache camel.

```
@Component
class ReadEmailRouteBuilder(var stockLocationProperty: 
StockLocationProperty) : RouteBuilder() {

    override fun configure() {
    //TODO
    }
}
```

This is the start i have to use and i have tried many ways but it never worked, can someone help me?

Comment: duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25763655/read-all-mails-from-gmail-inbox-using-apache-camel

Comment: I tried it, but it crash on  context.getEndpoint with the following error :   org.apache.camel.ResolveEndpointFailedException: Failed to resolve endpoint: imaps://imap.gmail.com?closeFolder=false&consumer.delay=60000&delete=false&disconnect=false&password=Ambra321%40&peek=false&unseen=true&username=CamelMail%40gmail.com due to: No component found with scheme: imaps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dependending on what protocol you are using (IMAP for instance), the answer could look like :

```
from("imaps://imap.gmail.com?username={{gmail.username}}&password={{gmail.password}}&delete=false&unseen=true&consumer.delay=60000")
    .process(new MailAttachmentProcessor())
    .to("file://gmails");
```

Comment: Do you have any error message ? What exactly does not work (compilation, execution, bad data, ...) ?

Comment: This is the error :javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: [AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] Invalid credentials (Failure)

Comment: OK, so we will start with the obvious : Could you please try to connect with this user and password to the gmail webmail ? I know it's obvious, but we never know until we try. Second, could you please confirm what you put in imaps://imap.gmail.com?username={{gmail.username}} in the place of {{gmail.username}} ?

Comment: I changed the account security settings and it works. Now i can take the Attachments with : exchange.getIn().getAttachments() but i don't know how take the text of the email

Comment: Mmmm... I would suggest : String body = exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);